# How to get a value from a dropdown menu to send in an e-mail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, email, drop-down-menu

In React I've got a contact from made with name, e-mail, and a message box working just fine. On submit those three items send through like they should. However I'm trying to get a selected item from a dropdown menu to send along with it as well. I'm assuming it's probably not as cut and dry as the other three items, but I'm at a loss on this one. Thanks!

Here's my contact form page.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';
import Data from './data.json'
import Select from 'react-select'

export const Email = () => {
  const form = useRef();

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('xxxxx', 'xxxxxx', form.current, 'xxxxxx')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
  };

  console.log(sendEmail);

  return (
    <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail} className="flex flex-col mx-7 md:w-[30%] md:mx-auto">
      <label className="font-semibold">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="user_name" className="rounded-md border-2 border-purple-500"/>
      <label className="font-semibold">Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="user_email" className="rounded-md border-2 border-purple-500"/>
      <label className="font-semibold">Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" className='rounded-md border-2 border-purple-500'/>
      <Select name="title" options={Data} />
      <input type="submit" value="Send" className="font-semibold w-16 mx-auto mt-7 rounded-md bg-purple-300 hover:cursor-pointer hover:border-purple-800 hover:bg-purple-500 border-2 border-purple-500"/>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Here's the Data list I'm importing and playing with that I'm trying to send a selected option from.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Cheese Burger",
        "label": "four"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Bacon Burger",
        "label": "five"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple solution to this one. With `<Select />` being a custom component {read: nested all to gravy} that doesn't have the inner workings to interface with a `<form>` you are going to have to utilize an outside library.

I went with [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/), but there are other form libraries you can use out there such as [formik](https://formik.org/).

Edit: I am using the syntax for v7 of react-hook-form
[v6 -> v7](https://legacy.react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/)

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';
import Data from './data.json'
import Select from 'react-select'

export const Email = () => {
  // react-hook-form functions / state 
  const { handleSubmit, register, control  } = useForm()

  // update the submit function for emailjs.send
  const sendEmail = (data) => {
    emailjs.send('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', data, 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text)
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text)
      })
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(sendEmail) } className="flex flex-col mx-7 md:w-[30%] md:mx-auto">
      <label className="font-semibold">Name</label>
      <input {...register('user_name')} type="text" className="rounded-md border-2 border-purple-500"/>

      <label className="font-semibold">Email</label>
      <input {...register('user_email')} type="email" className="rounded-md border-2 border-purple-500"/>

      <label className="font-semibold">Message</label>
      <textarea {...register('message')} className='rounded-md border-2 border-purple-500'/>

      <Controller 
        name='select'
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => (
            <Select {...field}  options={Data} />
        )}
      />

      <input type="submit" value="Send" className="font-semibold w-16 mx-auto mt-7 rounded-md bg-purple-300 hover:cursor-pointer hover:border-purple-800 hover:bg-purple-500 border-2 border-purple-500"/>
    </form>
  )
}
```

You are going to register each of your inputs and any custom component like `<Select>` is going to be wrapped in the `<Controller />` component imported from react-hook-form.

You can do as much or as little as you like with this, but the above example is the most bare bones without any sort of field validation, rules or the like.

The submitted form data will take the form of a json object with the keys being the names passed into the register function or in the case of the controller the name attribute.

You can then access these values the same way you were accessing them before in your email template.
`{{user_name}} {{user_email}} {{message}}` and the like for those simple values.
Since I really didn't know what you wanted passed from your data objects I passed the whole object to your sendEmail function under the name `select`. On your email template side you'll get the values like so: `{{select.id}} {{select.label}} {{select.title}}`.

Trying to get your value from an object in your email template with just the name of the object `{{select}}` will print out `[object Object]` in your email instead of any information.